# Inheriting System.Windows.Controls.Panel

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I use the `Panel` to provide custom layout of UIElements.
For this, I override `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride`. In `ArrangeOverride` proper locations are given to Children.

In my application, there is a bunch of rather heavy (by number of visuals) children inside the panel, but only 2 of them are located inside the visible region at a time.

Working with my application I feel like *all* the visuals are drown.

I need to introduce a kind of 'virtualization' and make the children render (or *take CPU cycles*) selectively.

How do I?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this topic: [WPF VirtualizingStackPanel for increased performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389769/wpf-virtualizingstackpanel-for-increased-performance)

Answer (score 0):

If your panel is placed inside a ScrollViewer, you can implement [IScrollInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.iscrollinfo.aspx).
Can be quite a bit of code though, but there a couple of blogs out there with examples, for example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/bencon/archive/2006/01/05/509991.aspx) and [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-implementing-iscrollinfo)

I found that [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/dancre/archive/2006/02/06/implementing-a-virtualized-panel-in-wpf-avalon.aspx) blog post describes more closely what you're trying to accomplish, though not exactly.