# WP7 How to display data in TextBlock?

Tags: windows-phone-7, richtextbox, textblock

I created a TextBlock link this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="content" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="40"/>

String largeText = "";

content.Text=largeText;
```

`largeText` has 3000 pixels, but only 2048 are being displayed. It shows empty text after that.

How can I show `largeText` in TextBlock?

Comment: try wrapping the TextBlock with a ScrollViewer

Comment: i am this format only. showing 2048px after other text coming empty space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this scrollabletextbox control - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx

However, its important to note that such large chunks of text are going to have serious impacts on your applications performance, and you should consider some kind of pagination for your text content, as mentioned in this question - [wp7 - TextBlock with a lot of text - huge memory usage - how to avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853264/wp7-textblock-with-a-lot-of-text-huge-memory-usage-how-to-avoid-it)

Answer (score 0):

The display limit for Windows Phone is 2048 pixels for the height or width of any control. You can't display larger content in a single control.