# flip in pages in Wpf with add pages dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create application in which I want to give flip effect to each pages,
I mean I want my application work and look like book.
also I want to add pages dynamically when ever I want to add pages to application.
suppose, I have 20 pages in application, now from admin panel  want to add some pages to application,so that added pages also show in flip effect.

Is this possible?

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about implementing infinite scroll within WPF (see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691467/wpf-listbox-generate-items-as-user-scrolls). The question is not exactly the same, but the answer is very relevant to what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There was a good sample of doing this (flip effect): http://wpfbookcontrol.codeplex.com/

I'm not sure about how you will add pages dynamically. What you are trying to solve? You want to pack your application with different set of pages? Or you want to have Client-Server solution? In both cases - don't see why this is impossible.

Comment: thanx for answer,let me explain,suppose i have 20 pages now in future i want to add 20 more pages so total 40 pages are their ,so now i want new added pages also work like old 20 pages without any coding change.

Comment: As I understand these pages will be part of resources near your WPF app, right? If so - I guess you can just keep all pages as a PNG files, load them from specific directory by specific order (1.png, 2.png, 3.png, etc) and show them in the same order. So your application can just enumerate all files from specific location and generate pages by these files. Each file is a page.