# wpf UI freezes when opening Combobox with a large number of items

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I am working on a WPF Application where i have a combobox with ItemsSource binded to a property of 5000 records coming from database. The problem is that when i click the dropdown arrow of combobox the UI not responding or combobox is taking too much time to respond. I searched it but nothing worked for me.

here is the code:

```
 <ComboBox IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding List,Mode=OneWay}" DisplayMemberPath="name" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                                    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <VirtualizingStackPanel VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                                </ComboBox>
```

and the property

```
  private ObservableCollection<Object> _List = new ObservableCollection<Object>();
        public ObservableCollection<Object> List
        {
            get { return _List ; }
            set { _List = value; OnPropertyChanged("List"); }
        }
```

Edit:
here is the code that loads data inside the constructor

```
  public FormVM()
        {
              List = new ObservableCollection<Object>(db.cat.ToList());
        }
```

Comment: Please provide a "reproducible" problem. This code runs as fast as lightning.

Comment: Is the data loaded from the database in advance or in response to opening the combobox? We need to see the code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Erno the data loaded from the database in advance. I loaded the data in constructor

Comment: @Bizhan the code is running but UI is taking to much time to respond

Comment: As I said, your problem is "not reproducible". So for us there is no problem. All is good. If I put a thread.sleep on the getter of `name` I will see what you explained, but without further info we can't help u

Comment: Anyways, you may want to read about different virtualizations: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1389769/366064

Comment: btw, there is no point in setting the ObservableCollection like that. just use a regular list. or add to the ObservableCollection.

Comment: Please! please test your code once before posting in here! I still don't see anything wrong. is the db.cat.name a Func? is it lazy loaded? please do a little more research

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to enable UI virtualization.

Currently UI virtualization is disabled for your `ComboBox`!

Controls like `ListBox` or `ListView` have this feature enabled by default.
Other controls that extend `ItemsControl` like `ComboBox` have to enable it explicitly.

To enable UI virtualization

1. The `ItemsPresenter` (or any `Panel` with `Panel.IsItemsHost` set to `True`) of the `ItemsControl` must be the child of a `ScrollViewer`.
   This is already the case for the `ComboBox`.
2. The `ScrollViewer` must be configured to scroll by items (logical units) instead of pixels (physical units) by setting the attached `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll` property to `True`.
3. `ItemsControl` must have its `ItemsPanel` set to a `VirtualizingStackPanel`.
4. The virtualization mode of the `VirtualizingPanel` must be enabled by setting the attached property `VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing` to `True`.

**Example**

```
<ComboBox VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
  <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <VirtualizingStackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
</ComboBox>
```

Further improvements can be achieved by enabling deferred scrolling:

```
<ComboBox ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True" />
```

Satisfying one of the following conditions will make UI virtualization impossible:

- Item containers are added directly to the `ItemsControl`. For example,
  if an application explicitly adds `ListBoxItem` objects to a `ListBox`,
  the `ListBox` does not virtualize the `ListBoxItem` objects.
- Item containers in the `ItemsControl` are of different types. For
  example, a Menu that uses `Separator` objects cannot implement item
  recycling because the Menu contains objects of type `Separator` and
  `MenuItem`.
- Setting `CanContentScroll` to false.
- Setting `IsVirtualizing` to false.

If you have followed every constraint then UI virtualization does work. You then have a problem which is not related to UI virtualization. If yoou would set up a new empty project with just a `ComboBox` you should encounter no issues.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this. I never would have thought "CanContentScroll" would affect the virtualization, since I was using the listview and it has already a built-in scrollview.

Comment: @tataelm Thank you! The reason is that the panel must know when items leave/enter the viewport of the scroll viewer in order to be able to control container generalization/virtualization. Therefore, the panel needs logical scrolling (scroll by item). If you set `CanContentScroll` to `false`, you have physical scrolling (scroll by pixel). Scrolling vertically by "1" means: by 1 *item* when `CanContentScroll=true` or 1 *pixel* when `CanContentScroll=false`. Scrolling 1 *item* always means 1 item has become hidden/visible. But 1 pixel you can never know when an item becomes hidden/visible.